# Insert a data in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables, leagues and teams. I have no problem creating a league, but I am having a trouble creating a team in a particular league. When I create a team, it appears on all the leagues, I want to show it only on the league that I choose on my drop down box. This is my my drop down box (teams/form):

```
    <select style="width: 193px" type="text">
        <% @leagues.each do |league| %>
            <option><%= league.league_name %></option>
        <% end %>
    </select>
```

And this is my def new (teams_controller):

```
def new
    @team = Team.new

    @leagues = League.all
end
```

And my def create (teams_controller):

```
def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @team.save
            format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @team }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

I think it has something to do with the def create, but I don't know what. Please help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you wanna select the league which the team belongs to?, something like that? can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: My objective is to insert the data of the team I want to create to a particular league. The problem right now is, teams being created is being inserted on all the leagues.

Comment: Could you attach the model files and schema.rb ?